# error class name not recognized when installing package through module`s composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I created a module with Laravel Module and I want to install a package in a this module. The package was installed in a module's vendor but the problem is that its class is not defined somewhere else in the project.

Here is my composer.json :

```
{
"name": "nwidart/audit",
"description": "",
"authors": [
{
   "name": "Nicolas Widart",
   "email": "n.widart@gmail.com"
}
],
"extra": {
"laravel": {
"providers": [
    "Modules\\Audit\\Providers\\AuditServiceProvider"
],
"aliases": {

}
}
},
   "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
        "Modules\\Audit\\": "Modules/Audit/"
}
},
   "require": {
    "owen-it/laravel-auditing": "^9.2",
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: yes but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this package for merge composer.json files
https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin

just note :

```
{
"require": {
   "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "dev-master"
},
    "extra": {
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "composer.local.json",
                "Modules/*/composer.json"
            ],
            "require": [
                "Modules/Audit/composer.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "ignore-duplicates": false,
            "merge-dev": true,
            "merge-extra": false,
            "merge-extra-deep": false,
            "merge-scripts": false
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the package inside a module. You should use "composer merge plugin" for this problem or add it to the root of the project.